# Format code in Doxia Apt Format

Tags: maven, documentation, apt, doxia

I am currently starting to write a documentation for one of our projects. For reasons of simplicity we chose to use the Almost Plain Text (APT) Format, see more info here: 
http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/apt-format.html

APT is great documentation format, since it uses a minimal syntax and hence it is very easy to create and make changes to the documentation without knowing a lot about APT.

However, I couldn't find a way to format code in a nice way. Is there a code tag or similar, which can be used to include some source code? I'm aware I could use FML, but this would be less desirable.

Thanks

Comment: just saw this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/m2-site-tools/wiki/UserGuide 
however, the hightlight feature doesn't seem to work nether for java nor for xml.

Comment: there is also this project: http://doxia-include.sourceforge.net/usageAndReference.html. However, I could not build my pom.xml since the dependencies were missing: Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0-beta-3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact 
 org.tinyjee:doxia-include-macro:jar:1.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Comment: same problem with this project: http://syntax-highlighted-snippet.googlecode.com/svn/site/index.html

Answer (score 11):

For those who are still wondering how to make a code snipped in APT:

```
     This is regular text
+---------------------
This is a code snippet
+---------------------
      More regular text
```

Answer (score 3):

[Apache Maven Fluido](http://maven.apache.org/skins/maven-fluido-skin/) Skin highlights syntax out of the box. [Here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html) you can find an example. Information about syntax highlighting in Fluido: "Source code sections are enhanced by Google Code Prettify, users can optionally enable line numbers rendering (disabled by default)" from Fluido website.

Comment: The page of the link you provide in your example seems to be created with xdoc, not with APT (see https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/log4j2/trunk/src/site/xdoc/manual/markers.xml). Do you happen to know an example utilizing Fluido/Google Code Prettify with APT? (cannot make it happen with my project it seems... maybe I should resort to xdoc too)

Comment: @evandor Maven Fluido Skin project itself uses APT; [maven-fluido-skin](http://maven.apache.org/skins/maven-fluido-skin/) site is made using APT ([source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/skins/tags/maven-fluido-skin-1.3.0/src/site/apt/index.apt.vm?view=markup)).

Answer (score 3):

The

```
+---------------------
code
+---------------------
```

syntax is correct.  And Fluido does highlight using [Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) out of the box as others have mentioned.

However, a Doxia change in Site Plugin 3.3 broke Fluido.  [MSKINS-86](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSKINS-86) fixes this, but hasn't been released yet.

Workarounds

1. Use the site.xml [workaround](https://plus.google.com/116267359728910593612/posts/8MQM8Y4CTeu)

   `<body>
     <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
           $("div.source pre").addClass("prettyprint");
           prettyPrint();
         });
       </script>
     </head>
   </body>`
2. Use Site Plugin 3.2
3. Build the unreleased Fluido 1.4 that contains MSKINS-86 fix and use it instead of 1.3.1

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the snippet macro from the Doxia Macros Guide: http://maven.apache.org/doxia/macros/index.html#Snippet_Macro

It puts the code from the snippet file in a verbatim box. However it does not provide a syntax highlightning.

Comment: for those who are still wondering how to make a code snippet in APT:

+---------------------

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.0 of doxia include macro is not at maven central however the following versions are:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tinyjee.dim/doxia-include-macro